# I have installed both jupyter-kite, jupyter-lsp and the corresponding plug-in successfully, but none of them are working properly。

Tags: jupyter-lab, kite

### 1 Running environment

- OS： windows 10
- Use the base virtual environment provided by conda
- jupyterlab: 3.0.14
- jupyterlab-kite: 2.0.2
- jupyterlab-lsp: 1.2.0

### 2 Problem description

- [The image of pulg-in installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAcO3.png)
- [The image of status of jupyter lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUh8R.png)

The kite desktop is running, but the kite icon is not displayed in the status bar of the lab. lsp is displayed correctly.
But neither of them work properly, provide code completion.

### 3 Methods that have been tried

1. Remove build_config.json from `Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab\settings`.
2. Reinstall jupyterlab, kite, lsp.
3. `jupyter lab clean/build`

**Thank you for your attention!!**

Comment: Do not install both. Install one or the other.

Comment: If you wish to use jupyterlab-lsp please uninstall jupyterlab-kite. You will also need to install a [language server](https://jupyterlab-lsp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Language%20Servers.html) for jupyterlab-lsp.

Comment: If this does not work please provide detailed environment information as requested by [this bug issue template](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md). Please let me know how it goes.